# разберите python код, в книге обьяснялось но я не понял

Tags: python

```
import os
import time
# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.
# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'E:\\Backup' # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете использовать.
# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
# Запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Импортируем необходимые модуль
- Сохраняем  в список ,что будем копировать
- Сохраняем в переменную ,куда будем копировать
- Чтобы копии разных времен не оверрайтелись , к имени каждой  копии (zip  архиву) добавляем дату.
- Архивируем и сохраняем
- Если копия прошла успешно: говорим `print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)`
  Иначе :
  `print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')`